# C# problems - System.FormatException was unhandled

Tags: c#, sql

I have a slight problem with one of my programs. In this one I have created a database in SQL about Sellers and Buyers of Different Paint (Colors like Green, Red and etc.). Then, when the database was complete I have created a Client app in C# and connected it to database. Each of the Tables in the database (name´s Fakturace - Billing, Bill) I am able to print on the dataGrid in my form2. And here the trouble starts - When I try to add another Reord of Seller or Buyer or Bill or Paint there is one exception that keeps popping up. It is in the Picture I included.

The code is:    `

```
    int id_kup;
    int id_barva;
    int id_faktura;

    string jm;
    string prijm;
    string tel_cisl;
    int cislo_uctu;
    string alias;
    int ičo;
    int dič;
    string adresa;

    int kod;
    string naz_bar;
    string znacka;
    string typ;
    int dph;
    double jedn_cena;
    double mnozstvi;

    string dat_splat;
    string dat_vyst;
    string datum_plneni;
    int var_sym; 
    int konst_symb;
    int id_prod1;
    int id_kup1;

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Visible = false;
        textBox2.Visible = false;
        textBox3.Visible = false;
        textBox4.Visible = false;
        textBox5.Visible = false;
        textBox6.Visible = false;
        textBox7.Visible = false;
        textBox8.Visible = false;
        textBox9.Visible = false;
        button14.Visible = false;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DBVrstva d1 = new DBVrstva();
        d1.nacti_prodejce(dataGridView1);
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DBVrstva d4 = new DBVrstva();
        d4.nacti_kupujícího(dataGridView2);
    }

    private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DBVrstva d7 = new DBVrstva();
        d7.nacti_barvu(dataGridView3);
    }

    private void button13_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DBVrstva d13 = new DBVrstva();
        d13.nacti_fakturu(dataGridView4);
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        jm = textBox2.Text;
        prijm = textBox3.Text;
        tel_cisl = textBox4.Text;
        cislo_uctu = Convert.ToInt32(textBox5.Text);
        alias = textBox6.Text;
        ičo = Convert.ToInt32(textBox7.Text);
        dič = Convert.ToInt32(textBox8.Text);
        adresa = textBox9.Text;

        textBox1.Visible = true;
        textBox2.Visible = true;
        textBox3.Visible = true;
        textBox4.Visible = true;
        textBox5.Visible = true;
        textBox6.Visible = true;
        textBox7.Visible = true;
        textBox8.Visible = true;
        textBox9.Visible = true;

        button14.Visible = true;

        try
        {
            String Cstr = @"server= BLACK-TOSHIBA\SQLEXPRESS;database = Fakturace;UID=sa;PWD=f10dr0v1c";
            string ctext = "insert into Prodejce(id_prod,jm,prijm,tel_cisl,cislo_uctu, alias, ičo,dič,adresa) values('" + id + "','" + jm + "','" + prijm + "','" + tel_cisl + "','" + cislo_uctu + "','" + alias + "','" + ičo + "','" + dič + "','" + adresa + "')";
            DBVrstva da = new DBVrstva();
            da.Transakce(ctext, Cstr);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Zadal jsi něco špatně");
        }
    }

    private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(" Ukončujete aplikaci! ");
        Application.Exit();
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         //odebrat prodavajiciho
    }

    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //pridat kupujiciho
        id_kup = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        jm = textBox2.Text;
        prijm = textBox3.Text;
        tel_cisl = textBox4.Text;
        cislo_uctu = Convert.ToInt32(textBox5.Text);
        alias = textBox6.Text;
        ičo = Convert.ToInt32(textBox7.Text);
        dič = Convert.ToInt32(textBox8.Text);
        adresa = textBox9.Text;

        textBox1.Visible = true;
        textBox2.Visible = true;
        textBox3.Visible = true;
        textBox4.Visible = true;
        textBox5.Visible = true;
        textBox6.Visible = true;
        textBox7.Visible = true;
        textBox8.Visible = true;
        textBox9.Visible = true;

        button14.Visible = true;

        textBox1.Text = "";
        textBox2.Text = "";
        textBox3.Text = "";
        textBox4.Text = "";
        textBox5.Text = "";
        textBox6.Text = "";
        textBox7.Text = "";
        textBox8.Text = "";
        textBox9.Text = "";

        try
        {
            String Cstr = @"server= BLACK-TOSHIBA\SQLEXPRESS;database = Fakturace;UID=sa;PWD=f10dr0v1c";
            string ctext = "insert into Kupující(id_kup,jm,prijm,tel_cisl,cislo_uctu, alias, ičo,dič,adresa) values('" + id_kup + "','" + jm + "','" + prijm + "','" + tel_cisl + "','" + cislo_uctu + "','" + alias + "','" + ičo + "','" + dič + "','" + adresa + "')";
            DBVrstva da = new DBVrstva();
            da.Transakce(ctext, Cstr);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Zadal jsi něco špatně");
        }
    }

    private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //odebrat prodavajiciho
    }

    private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //pridat barvu

        textBox1.Visible = true;
        textBox2.Visible = true;
        textBox3.Visible = true;
        textBox4.Visible = true;
        textBox5.Visible = true;
        textBox6.Visible = true;
        textBox7.Visible = true;
        textBox8.Visible = true;

        id_barva = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        kod = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
        naz_bar = textBox3.Text;
        znacka = textBox4.Text;
        typ = textBox5.Text;
        dph = Convert.ToInt32(textBox6.Text);
        jedn_cena = Convert.ToDouble(textBox7.Text);
        mnozstvi = Convert.ToDouble(textBox8.Text);

        try
        {
            String Cstr = @"server= BLACK-TOSHIBA\SQLEXPRESS;database = Fakturace;UID=sa;PWD=f10dr0v1c";
            string ctext = "insert into Barva(id_barva, kod, naz_bar,znacka, typ, dph, jedn_cena, mnozstvi) values('" + id_barva + "','" + kod + "','" + naz_bar + "','" + znacka + "','" + typ + "','" + dph + "','" + jedn_cena + "','" + mnozstvi + "')";
            DBVrstva da = new DBVrstva();
            da.Transakce(ctext, Cstr);

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Zadal jsi něco špatně");
        }

    }

    private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //odebrat barvu
    }

    private void button12_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //pridat fakturu

        textBox1.Visible = true;
        textBox2.Visible = true;
        textBox3.Visible = true;
        textBox4.Visible = true;
        textBox5.Visible = true;
        textBox6.Visible = true;
        textBox7.Visible = true;
        textBox8.Visible = true;
        textBox9.Visible = true;

        id_faktura = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        dat_splat = textBox2.Text;
        dat_vyst = textBox3.Text;
        datum_plneni = textBox4.Text;
        var_sym = Convert.ToInt32(textBox5.Text);
        konst_symb = Convert.ToInt32(textBox6.Text);
        id_prod1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox7.Text);
        id_kup1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox8.Text);
        int id_bar1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox9.Text);

         try
        {
            String Cstr = @"server= BLACK-TOSHIBA\SQLEXPRESS;database = Fakturace;UID=sa;PWD=f10dr0v1c";
            string ctext = "insert into Faktura(id_faktura,dat_splat,dat_vyst,datum_plneni,var_sym,konst_symb,id_prod1,id_kup1,id_bar1) values('" + id_faktura + "','" + dat_splat + "','" + dat_vyst + "','" + datum_plneni + "','" + var_sym + "','" + konst_symb + "','" + id_prod1 + "','" + id_kup1 + "','" + id_bar1 + "',' )";
            DBVrstva da = new DBVrstva();
            da.Transakce(ctext, Cstr);

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Zadal jsi něco špatně");
        }

    }

    private void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //odebrat fakturu
    }

}
```

`

Note that this is just code of the Form2 - there is Also form 1 that is used to log in the appand Class named DBVrstava which I am using to support the connection to the database and the SQL server.

[image]

Comment: `textbox1.Text` just contains some non-numeric values probably

Comment: I can see you are trying to add value of ID ... google a bit about int identity(1,1) columns in SQL ... also, solution to this problem, we need you to give us value of textbox1.text that you are trying to insert

Comment: I am writing a number (id to differ each record in every table ) in the textBox1, but the trouble is that whe i hit the button to anable the textboxes to show up and fill them with the information like id, names and etc it instantly stop and the exception pops up - You are maybe right but there is also the stuff with the exception that keeps telling me that i am using string for DateTime not for integer value as I think I am doing. But i still dont know how to fix it?

Comment: id identity is not an issuse since i made the key that i can add the value myself  - this is the table in sql

Comment: CREATE
  TABLE Barva
  (
    id_barva INTEGER NOT NULL ,
    kod NVARCHAR (55) NOT NULL ,
    naz_bar NVARCHAR (55) NOT NULL ,
    znacka NVARCHAR(55) NOT NULL ,
    typ NVARCHAR (55) NOT NULL ,
    dph       INTEGER NOT NULL ,
    jedn_cena INTEGER NOT NULL ,
    mnozstvi  INTEGER NOT NULL
  ) ;
ALTER TABLE Barva ADD CONSTRAINT Barva_PK PRIMARY KEY
(
  id_barva
)
;

Comment: The value that I want is number 4 - that should be the following record number for the insert

Comment: Put a break point on that line ... and then try to insert ... once software hit break point, point the mouse on Text property of TextBox1 ... let me know what is in there ... also what you can try is use Trim() function to make sure there is no white space

Comment: Sorry Guys - I have already solved the issue and I feel terrible dumb. :D

Comment: The problém was that the button2 was not just allowing the textboxes and tha button 14 - it also tried to add the record in the exact same moment that the textboxes apperead totaly blank - so it had no information in them and still tried to execute the insert!

Comment: OT Please rename those buttons and textboxes - will *you* remember in a month what "TextBox9" is about ?

Comment: I have made some comments to them by now - so Yes i will know which button does what, but you are right I should start working on it - it is much easier than looking for green text behind backslashes as so on

Comment: You might want to remove the user and password fields from the connection strings in your post.